# I have problem with "context" in my GestureDetector?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to redirect my application when I press one of my columns, but I have an error in the `onPressed() (): {Navigator.push () the "context" is not defined. but I don't know how to pass context.

Maybe the solution is easy but this is my first time working with flutter

The method onPressed is in the first `GestureDetector()`.

```
    class ProductDataGridSource extends DataGridSource {
      ProductDataGridSource(this.productList) {
        buildDataGridRow();
      }
      late List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows;
      late List<Product> productList;
    
      @override
      DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
        return DataGridRowAdapter(cells: [
          GestureDetector(
             child: TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue,
                  onSurface: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
                },
                child: Text(row.getCells()[0].value.toString()),
              ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              print(row.getCells()[1].value.toString());
            },
            child: TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.blue,
                onSurface: Colors.red,
              ),
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text(row.getCells()[1].value.toString()),
            ),
          ),
    
        ]);
      }
```

Comment: You can pass the BuildContext from your parent widget

Comment: try to use "this.context" sometimes it get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a custom class you would need to add a member field to the class and pass it in from wherever you instantiate this class, for example:

```
class ProductDataGridSource extends DataGridSource {
  ProductDataGridSource(this.productList, required this.context) {
    buildDataGridRow();
  }
  late List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows;
  late List<Product> productList;
  final BuildContext context;
  
  ...
```

I added required only because you seem to need it and it's good practice to add "required" when constructing an object if it's crucial.

Then proceed to use context in your class, hope this helps!